# How can see any error if I can't install app from google play

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I have a problem in an app updated in play store.

Around 800 user could updated it without problem, but we have 3 users who get this message:

[image]

I've try install it with apk instead play store, with a similar result:
[image]

The min SDK is 16 and the SDK target is 28, and this devices have SDK 27 and 28.

One of these users had a device in which she couldn't install it. But last week buy new device, and she can't install it too. This new device has never had the application installed before.

How can I see any information about the problem?

Comment: I am also getting this issue with some users. Most of the time they get tired and stop using my app. Have you found a solution?

Comment: Did you fix the issue I am also getting same issue  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74820864/cannt-install-the-app-message-on-play-store-in-flutter-app

Answer (score 5):

I had such a problem, when tried to install a new version of my app. I found the reason for the problem when installing the new release version of my app using Android Studio. The error message has explained in detail what the problem is.

So if someone has such a problem I would suggest getting a device on which the error can be reproduced, then trying to install it using Android Studio and check the message.

The full story in my case was as the following: I had two different applicationId for "release" and "debug" configurations. In the new version of the app, I added a "provider" to the manifest. During my development I installed the debug version and then I deployed the new version to the Play Store. When I tried to install the deployed app on this device I got the message that it cannot be installed. The reason was that the release version had the same provider as the debug version, so they cannot be installed both. The solution is to change the authorities of the provider according to the applicationId.

Comment: This was the exact issue I was having and I don't know how many more hours/days I would have spent bashing my head against a wall had you not posted this. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a problem on the device, rather than a problem downloading from Google Play store. Logs from this should be in the users device logs, like you get for your app. You can ask your user for the logs, by asking them to send you a bug report. [There are instructions here](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/bug-report) on taking bug reports.

When you look at the bug report, error messages from the Play store are tagged with "Finsky". You may also see errors from the device package manager.

Answer (score 0):

When errors like this occured, it is recommended to read the link (see common ways to fix the problem). Most of the time cleaning Google Play Services cache and data will do the trick:

Clear the Google Play Store cache

1.Open the Settings menu on your device.

2.Go to Apps or Application Manager. (This option might differ depending on your device.)

3.Scroll to All apps and then scroll down to the Google Play Store app.

4.Open the app details and tap the Force stop button.

5.Tap the Clear cache button.

Repeat the steps above, but replace Google Play Store in step 3 with Google Play services.
Try to download the app again.

Clear the Google Play Store data
If cleaning the cache of the Google Play Store and Google Play Services doesn't resolve the issue, try clearing the Google Play Store data:

1.Open the Settings menu on your device.

2.Go to Apps or Application Manager. (This option might differ depending on your device.)

3.Scroll to All apps and then scroll down to the Google Play Store app.

4.Open the app details and tap the Force stop button.

5.Tap the Clear data button.

6.Clear data button

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We tried this before, but it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you install apk from unknown source and then update the app from Play store
then play store never update your Application.
but if you install the App from play store and Update the App, Then Play store will update the Application

Answer (score 0):

In android/app/build.gradle - remove compileSdkPreview "UpsideDownCake" libe if you added before and use implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.7.1' ( use latest stable version via here https://androidx.tech/artifacts/activity/activity-ktx/ ) in the implementations and clean your project and take build again - it worked for me in flutter 3.10