# Cann't install the app message on play store in Flutter App

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, updates

I have recently published an update (version xx(x.x.x)) on Myapp on the play store. I am getting an error message (Can't install Myapp) please check the attached screenshots. when a user tries to update the app, however, the initial install (if the user uninstalls the existing app and installs the app again) is working fine. In my app, I have written a program to inform our users when we have a higher version available on the play store. This feature redirects users to the app store to install updates. It works alright. Before the release of this version, users were able to install the updates.
I have already tried suggested options like clearing the play store's cache and allowing updating apps on all networks, etc.
Looking for your guidance to solve this issue.[image]

My pubspec.yaml

```
name: xxx
description: A new Flutter application.

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.9.0+21

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.12.0 <3.0.0'


dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:

    sdk: flutter
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.4
  http: ^0.13.4
  #firebase_core_platform_interface: 4.5.2 # note removed ^
  firebase_messaging: ^14.1.4 # previously I only had this which was pulling in 4.5.2 which you do not want
  firebase_core: ^2.4.0
  sqflite: ^2.0.2
  path_provider: ^2.0.9
  device_info: ^2.0.3
  mime_type: ^1.0.0
  expandable: ^5.0.1
  permission_handler: ^9.2.0
  connectivity: ^3.0.6
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.13
  datetime_picker_formfield: ^2.0.0
  intl: ^0.17.0
  flutter_speed_dial: ^5.0.0+1
  camera: ^0.9.7+1
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.8
  video_player: ^2.2.10
  url_launcher: ^6.1.4
  file_picker: ^4.5.1
  image_picker: ^0.8.4+11
  share_plus: ^4.0.4
  quiver: ^3.0.1+1
  syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer: ^19.4.50-beta
  sms_autofill: ^2.2.0
  flutter_native_image: ^0.0.6
  whatsapp_unilink: ^2.0.2
  smooth_star_rating_null_safety: ^1.0.4+2
  encrypt: ^5.0.1
  percent_indicator: 4.0.0
  paytm_allinonesdk: ^1.1.5
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.1.5
  package_info: ^2.0.2
  light_compressor: ^1.2.2
  firebase_remote_config: ^3.0.7
  flutter_html: ^2.2.1
  device_apps: ^2.2.0
  regexpattern: ^2.0.1
  eva_icons_flutter: ^3.1.0
  #dio: ^4.0.6
  http_client: ^1.5.1
  excel: ^2.0.0-null-safety-3
  footer: ^0.0.4
  #rxdart: ^0.27.5
  #hive_flutter: ^1.1.0
  cached_network_image: ^3.0.0
  #external_path: ^1.0.0
  #file_selector: ^0.9.2
  flutter_exif_rotation: ^0.5.1
  visibility_detector: ^0.3.3



  #equatable: ^2.0.3
  #flutter_bloc: ^8.0.1
  #formz: ^0.4.0
  #async: ^2.8.2
  #date_time_picker: ^2.1.0
  flutter_local_notifications: ^12.0.2


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/logo_new.png
    - assets/
    #    - assets/logo_xtra_trust.png
    - assets/XTRANET_CPS_Ver4.0.0_signed.pdf
    - assets/subscriber_agreement.pdf
    - assets/subscriber_agreement_hindi.pdf

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  fonts:
    - family: Poppins
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/poppins_regular.ttf
```

Comment: were you able to solve this issue? Encountered this one too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter app not able to update on Google Play Store (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76658506/flutter-app-not-able-to-update-on-google-play-store-android)

Answer (score 0):

- please installed old version of your app
- after this please watch the linked video steps and apply those steps. your problem will be solved, but my suggestion is that simultaneously watch steps and apply the steps one by one and click on the update button continuously. that's why your problem is solved and you will get to know where your app is stuck

Link : - https://www.google.com/search?q=Google+Play+Store+showing+Update+button+but+app+cant+update&rlz=1C1JJTC_enIN988IN988&oq=Google+Play+Store+showing+Update+button+but+app+cant+update&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.13673j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#fpstate=ive&vld=cid:3e3f7763,vid:k7rff10D1F4

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We have already tried all these ways and the thing is 8 out of 10 users are unable to install the update So it looks like the problem is either some dependency we are using of some configuration issue.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem a few days ago.

We have released 2.0 of existing app. So the version number also changes to 2.0(some big num). After that, we face this issue. But all update with 2.0 we can install there was no problem we face.

Check anything suspicious in your version number.